# Find linear transformation such that N(T)=R(T)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Well the title quite says it all, only I must say $T:\mathbb{R}^{2} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{2}$. I understand that $N(T)=\{v:T(v)=0\}=\{T(v):v\in \mathbb{R}^{2}\}=R(T)$ implies that $T(T(v))=0$ for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, but I'm not sure if it also implies that all $v \in N(T)$, that is, $N(T)=R(T)=\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Another possibility would be that $N(T)=\{0\}$. I tried to test these hypothesis but I found nothing. The truth is I'm not really sure how to approach the problem in the first place. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint:* Send one basis vector to zero; send the other basis vector to the first.

Comment: Also: what about $T = 0$?

Comment: I wish that people posting questions like this one would specify that $N(T)$ denotes the kernel (or null space) of $T$ and that $R(T)$ denotes the image (or range) subspace of $T$. Those are not standard notations, $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{Im} T$ (or $\operatorname{Range} T$) are much more so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem and by the hypothesis $N(T)=R(T)$ we get $$\dim N(T)=\dim R(T)=1$$
and as you mentioned we have $T^2=0$ which means that $T$ is nilpotent. Let $N(T)=\operatorname{span}(v)$ and complete it on a basis $(v,w)$ so $T(w)=\alpha v$ and then the matrix of $T$ relative to this basis is

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&\alpha\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just take $T(a,b)=(0,a)$. we are done.